# Calculate order price by date selection value

Tags: javascript, forms

Alright, I know there's a simple way to do this, but it's been years since I've done much javascript

My client has an online order form for event registration (developed by previous web dev.). Currently the order total is just a hidden field:

```
<INPUT value=78.00 type=hidden name=amount />
```

But I need the total to calculate based on what date they choose:

```
<SELECT style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ffff99" name=altDate1>
<OPTION value=04/09> Friday, April 9 </OPTION>
<OPTION value=04/14> Wednesday, April 14 </OPTION>
<OPTION value=04/16> Friday, April 16 </OPTION>
<OPTION value=04/19> Monday, April 19 </OPTION>
<OPTION value=04/29> Thursday, April 29 </OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

This is the javascript that process the form:

```
<SCRIPT language=Javascript> 

function PaymentButtonClick() {

    document.addform.Product_Name.value = document.Information.StudentLastName.value + ","+ 
                                          document.Information.StudentFirstName.value+","+
                                          document.Information.StudentID.value+","+
                                          document.Information.altDate1.name+","+","+
                                          document.Information.Guests.value+ "," + 
                                          document.Information.StudentType.value;

    document.addform.Product_Code.value = document.Information.StudentID.value;


    if ((document.Information.UCheck.checked==true) &&
        (document.Information.altDate1.value != "") && 
        (document.Information.altDate1.value != "x")) {

        if (document.Information.StudentLastName.value != "" ||
            document.Information.StudentFirstName.value != "" ||
            document.Information.StudentID.value != "" )  {

                document.addform.submit();
        }
        else { 
            alert("Please enter missing information");
        } 
    }
}

</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: I've cleaned up your code, but it's not clear to me what you need to do. Do you need to calculate a total amount based on weeks selected? Is it a multiple select? What does the rest of the form look like?

Comment: Sorry, it's an select/option field. The user selects a date, enters their contact info, and proceeds to payment. Sort of like conference/event registration. Their payment reserves a spot on the date they select, but the cost varies depending on the date they select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert this `switch` statement into your form processing function:

```
switch (document.Information.altDate1.value) {
    case '04/09':
        document.Information.amount.value = 78.00;
        break;
    case '04/14':
        document.Information.amount.value = 79.00;
        break;
    case '04/16':
        document.Information.amount.value = 80.00;
        break;
    case '04/19':
        document.Information.amount.value = 81.00;
        break;
    case '04/29':
        document.Information.amount.value = 82.00;
        break;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error when I submit the form:

Message: 'document.Information.amount' is null or not an object
Line: 193
Char: 9
Code: 0

Comment: Strange. Is that hidden field named "amount" not inside the form named "Information"?

Comment: The date select option is in "Information"
The hidden input value was in "addform"

There's 2 forms on the page, "Information" and "addform action=...>

I tried changing the form names in the switch statement you gave me to addform, but got the same error with document.addform.amount.

From what I remember, you don't ever need 2 forms on one page. I blame the problems on the genius that had this job before me.

Comment: There are occasions you'd need two... but only for completely separate things, like one is an always-present site search field, and the other is a registration form.

I'm surprised changing it to `document.addform.amount` didn't work. You could try putting an `id` on the hidden amount field and using `document.getElementById['amount'].value` instead of `document.addform.amount.value`.